# sbt run failed spark@3.2.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I maded a simple spark app in [this repository](https://github.com/sammyne/spark-failure-with-sbt-run), where `sbt run` always report errors as

```sh
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /github.com/sammyne/spark-failure-with-sbt-run/target/bg-jobs/sbt_28d6c4e/target/2ab34e8d/81ecd14d/hadoop-client-api-3.3.1.jar
```

### Environment

- sbt 1.6.2
- Scala 2.13.8
- Spark 3.2.1
- Ubuntu 20.04

### Bug reproduction

Both of the following two cases trigger errors like `NoSuchFileException`, which are expected to run successfully.

#### `sbt run` in one shot

```sh
sbt run
```

Partial errors go as

```sh
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /github.com/sammyne/spark-failure-with-sbt-run/target/bg-jobs/sbt_b7a00768/target/2ab34e8d/81ecd14d/hadoop-client-api-3.3.1.jar
```

The full logs can be seen [here](https://github.com/sammyne/spark-failure-with-sbt-run#sbt-run-in-one-shot).

#### `sbt` and then `run`

```sh
sbt

# after entering the sbt shell
run
```

At this moment, it's fine with logs as [here](https://github.com/sammyne/spark-failure-with-sbt-run#sbt-and-then-run).

However, once exit the shell, I got

```sh
[info] shutting down sbt server
22/04/27 07:55:10 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
22/04/27 07:55:10 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-f28ecf9a-e963-459f-b54e-f1e4825ba210
22/04/27 07:55:10 ERROR Configuration: error parsing conf core-default.xml
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /github.com/sammyne/spark-failure-with-sbt-run/target/bg-jobs/sbt_28d6c4e/target/2ab34e8d/81ecd14d/hadoop-client-api-3.3.1.jar
        at 
...
```

The full error can be seen as [here](https://github.com/sammyne/spark-failure-with-sbt-run#sbt-and-then-run)

Comment: Hi, I have the same running on MacOS. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Adding `run / fork := true` helps. @RobertGabriel

Comment: That did not work for me, I'm getting some other error now :). But thanks for taking the time to reply.